# [42S22][1054] Unknown column 'alex12345' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to get the value of the `verified` column from the verification table, by using the `username` field. The two tables, `user` and `verification`, are joined on the `user_id`. I've tried multiple combinations but they all seem to fail and produce the same result: `[42S22][1054] Unknown column 'alex12345' in 'where clause'`.

**PHP Code:**

```php
if (isset($_SESSION)){
        if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
            $username = $_SESSION['username'];

            $query = "SELECT v.verified FROM verification v join user u on u.user_id = v.user_id WHERE username = :username;";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute([':username' => $username]);
        }
}
```

**Attempts:**

```sql
SELECT verified FROM verification WHERE user_id = (SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE username = :username);
SELECT v.verified FROM verification v WHERE v.user_id = (SELECT u.user_id  FROM user u WHERE username = :username);

SELECT verified from verification
join user u on verification.user_id = u.user_id
where u.username = ?;
```

**Schema:**

[image]

Comment: can you show us the raw sql that is being processed, that gives the error, seems that a value is being taken as column

Comment: show your code that is replacing :username/? with alex12345

Comment: The only case where that would happen is if the part replacing `:username` or `?` is doing it incorrectly. Is this done by you? Or a library, and if so which library (and version)?

Comment: The query is actually run from a php file with the following code: `$query = "SELECT v.verified FROM verification v join user u on u.user_id = v.user_id WHERE username = :username;";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute([':username' => $username]);`
but it doesn't seem to work either through the SQL command line.

Comment: This shouldn't happen with the PDO prepared statement you show. It would only happen if you substituted the variable directly into the SQL string and forgot to quote it. Are you sure this is the code you're executing?

Comment: There's no way that the given example using `$stmt->execute([':username' => $username])` would generate the error `Unknown column 'alex12345'`.  Are you sure the page you're running has actually been updated to the new code?  *(Change the test username to `'BobbityBob'` and see if the error message changes with it.)*